# Qualtrics: Transform piped variable using javascript and display it in text?

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

Let there be a piped variable in qualtrics (a variable holding values recalled from a previous input by a survey respondent), how do I transform it to lower-case before displaying it?

There is the java-script function `.toLowerCase();` but how do I change a variable in the qualtrics custom javascript and pipe it back into a survey text?

[This link](http://www.qualtrics.com/university/researchsuite/developer-tools/custom-programming/survey-javascript-methods/) explains how to use piped variables in javascript. Say I define a new variable in javascript like this

```
// my piped variable is ${q://QID12/ChoiceGroup/SelectedAnswers}"
var selectedChoice = "${q://QID12/ChoiceGroup/SelectedAnswers}";
var selectedChoiceLower = selectedChoice.toLowerCase();
```

How to pipe selectedChoiceLower back into a question text?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `setEmbeddedData()` function to assign `selectedChoiceLower` to a new or existing embedded data variable ([see documentation](https://ut1.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/QuestionAPI/classes/Qualtrics%20JavaScript%20Question%20API.html#method_setEmbeddedData)). Then, you can use the embedded field variable in a later question.

javascript: `setEmbeddedData('lower', selectedChoiceLower);`

embedded field code: `${e://Fields/lower}`

**warning:** putting user-generated text into your javascript is very dangerous! Qualtrics does not do any escaping. If a user puts a ' or " in their text, it will be put directly into the javascript and probably break your code. Code injection is also possible. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256458/escaping-qualtrics-piped-text-for-use-in-javascript-more-generally-how-to-safe) for more details.

Comment: thanks, especially also for the warning which is important for novices like me.

Comment: What doesn't work? For what? And what happens instead?